# Troubleshooting COPY errors on AWS Redshift

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift

#### Update: If figured this out but am still interested in an explanation. The problem was that I was running the code below while also connected to my Redshift cluster from SqlWorkbenchJ (both running on the same laptop). The second I disconnect my SqlWorkbenchJ session and re-run my code, it doesn't hang. **Why?**

---

**Please note:** Although I mention Java/JDBC in this question, it is strictly a question about troubleshooting Redshift and is language/framework-agnostic!!!

---

Also here's an SSCCE repo that perfectly reproduces the hanging issue:
https://github.com/bitbythecron/redshift-copy-troubleshooting

I'm trying to run the following Redshift COPY command from Java code (using Postgres JDBC driver):

```
COPY my_schema.mytable
FROM 's3://com.example.mybucket/mydata.csv/part-00000-bc1b179d-b4c1-459f-8f5e-8fe361d4b40f-c000.csv'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::blah:role/MyRedshiftRole'
csv;
```

If I've read the docs right, this should:

1. Read a CSV file stored on S3
2. Copy its contents into a Redshift table (`my_schema.mytable`)

When I run this command in my Redshift UI client (SqlWorkbenchJ) it executes correctly and runs in a few seconds. However when I execute the following JDBC code (using the **exact** same connection URL, credentials, etc.) the code just hangs at the `executeUpdate` command:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement statement = null;
try {
  Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.setProperty("user", redshiftInfo.username);
  props.setProperty("password", redshiftInfo.password);

  log.info("\n\nAttempting to connect!\n\n");

  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://<sameExactUrl_thatIUser_inSqlWorkbenchJ>", props);

  log.info("\n\nConnection made!\n\n");

  statement = conn.createStatement();

  String command = "COPY my_schema.my_table FROM 's3://com.example.mybucket/mydata.csv/part-00000-bc1b179d-b4c1-459f-8f5e-8fe361d4b40f-c000.csv' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::blah:role/MyRedshiftRole' csv";

  log.info("\n\nExecuting...\n\n");

  statement.executeUpdate(command);

  log.info("\n\nHey I think it worked!!!\n\n");

  statement.close();
  conn.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.info(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
}
```

When this runs, in the logs I get to the `Executing...` log statement, but then the software just hangs. I've waited for as long as 30 minutes to see if it was just slow for some reason. I've also refreshed my SqlWorkbenchJ connection throughout (and after) this 30 minutes and ran `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_schema.my_table` and the count is always 0. So its making the connection but then nothing is actually being copied, or if it is, its not being committed.

I'd like to see what's happening on the Redshift side of things: are there any tables or logs (in the AWS console or otherwise) I can tail or inspect to see if records are actually being copied and staged somewhere, or to see if there are any errors being thrown reported from Redshift's perspective?

Comment: There is a Redshift console where you can see all queries and loads being performed. Services -> Redshift -> Clusters -> Your cluster -> Queries/Loads tabs.

Comment: Have you tried using `PreparedStatement`? Something like: `PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(command); stmt.execute();`

Comment: Is the code running from the same system (laptop or whatever) as when you run it via SqlWorkbenchJ? Do you see anything in stl_load_errors table? If not then probably permissions related. The role in the copy is for redshift to access s3. Permissions for client to execute on redshift are separate.

Comment: Yes running the code on the same laptop as where I have SqlWorkbenchJ installed, using the same user/password, using the same exact (verbatim) COPY command. :-/ And I think the important thing is the hanging, I would expect if it was permission/security related to get some kind of exception thrown.

Comment: @DanW mind taking a look at my update, any thoughts there? Thanks again!

Comment: It might be possible that your Redshift instance only allows a single connection at a time. To test this, you could try running your copy command first and then try connecting SQL Workbench.

Comment: Thanks @DanW but this wouldn't make any sense, it would be a non-starter business model for AWS. Besides https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/manage-connection-limits-redshift/ shows connection limits of up to 500. I've also ran other software (using Spark-Redshift library; not JDBC like I have here) that runs on multiple nodes and they have no problem connecting to the same Redshift cluster with the exact same connection string, credentials, etc. all at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was running the code below while also connected to my Redshift cluster from SqlWorkbenchJ (both running on the same laptop). The second I disconnect my SqlWorkbenchJ session and re-run my code, it doesn't hang.

Comment: Did you check the Autocommit box? See step 10 here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html
If you don't check it, SqlWorkbenchJ will keep locks open between queries until you explicitly execute `Commit;`

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your Java code. It works perfectly fine if number of records are less.

```
create table my_table (
  c_name            varchar(25)    not null,
  c_address         varchar(25)    not null,
  c_city            varchar(25)    not null);
```

Create a CSV with data# and put it in S3 with just 2-3 records,

```
one,two,three
example1,example2,example3
```

Then, run your code, it will following output.

```
 Attempting to connect!
 Connection made!
 Executing...
 Hey I think it worked!!!
```

Now, do

```
Select * from my_table;

 c_name  | c_address |  c_city
 ----------+-----------+----------
 one      | two       | three
 example1 | example2  | example3
```

Coming back to your question, why you see 0 records in `Select * from my_table;`

**Fact:**
Amazon Redshift is fully ACID Complaint, means until your copy command completed and committed, hence, you will not see any records in SELECT.

**Solution:**
You would like to see, what is happening with your query, whether getting executed or terminated?

You could run following command to see all the current running queries.

```
  select pid, user_name, starttime, query from stv_recents where status='Running';

  //OR

  select query, pid, elapsed, substring from svl_qlog where userid = 100 order by starttime desc limit 5;
```

Refer AWS Redshift [system query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_querying_redshift_system_tables.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Red Boy, however the main concern I have with your answer is the fact that SqlWorkbenchJ (also written in pure Java) can execute this command in 9 seconds against the same CSV file. So it shouldn't take my code > 30 minutes to execute!

Comment: Also @Red Boy please check this out if you get a chance: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/191245/149517 -- any chance its relevant to the Redshift COPY command?

Comment: OK @Red Boy mind taking a look at my update? I figured out the problem but still would like a deeper understanding of *why* this was happening. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup hmm interesting. I didn't focus on SQLWorkbenchJ information. Stackoverflow is great place to know surprises we developers encounter on day to day basis. :)